# old() does not work on dependent dropdown in Laravel blade

Tags: laravel

I have two dropdown list in my Laravel page. I am trying to get old value of the dependent dropdown list (`categorylist.blade`) and make it selected once I fill and post the data. It returns back to the same page if the validation has not successfully completed. I am able to get all values except this one. I have tried `Session::put()` as well as `Session::flash()` but did not work. The category list is retrieved once you chose section as it requests the category list from the controller through ajax. How can I get the old value in the category dropdown list after the page refreshed.

Here is my section selection dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control sectionchoose" name="section_id" id="section_id">
    <option value="">Choose Section</option>
    @foreach($sections as $section)
        <option value="{{$section['id']}}" @if(old('section_id') == $section['id']) selected @endif>{{$section['name']}} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

My categorylist dropdown:

```
<label class="col-sm-6">Chose Category</label>
<div class="categorylist">
@include('admin.deal-management.categorylist')
</div>
```

And this is my categorylist view file:

```
<select class="form-control " name="category_id" id="category_id">
    <option value="">Choose Category</option>
       @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{$category['id']}}" @if(old('category_id') == $category['id']) selected @endif>
                    {{$category['category_name']}}
                </option>
            @endforeach
      
</select>
```

and this is my main controller:

```
public function addEditDeals(DealAddEditRequest $request, $id=null){
//*** post starts here ***/
        if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $message = 'Updated successfully';
        $data=$request->all();
 
            $deal->fill($request->validated());
            $deal->save();

            return redirect()->back()->with($message);
        }
```

This is my categorylist controller:

```
public function findCategories(Request $request){
    if($request->json()){
        $data = $request->all();
        $categories = Category::where(['section_id' => $data['id'], 'status'=>1])->get()->toArray();
        return view('admin.deal-management.categorylist',compact('categories'));
 }
}
```

And finally, this is the jQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    let sectionid = $('.sectionchoose').val();
    $.ajax({

        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        url : '/admin/selectsection',
        data: {id:sectionid},

        success: function(response){
            $('.categorylist').html(response)
        }, error:function(){

        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find the solution. Whoever has the same issue can use the approach below:

**Step 1:** Send the Session value through the `with()` command:

```
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput()->with('cat_id',$data['category_id']);

            }
```

**Step 2:** Retreive the data in your main blade and attain hidden input:

```
<input class="cat_id" id="asd" type="hidden" value="{{Session::get('cat_id')}}"/>
```

**Step 3:** Get the retreived session value in Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    let sectionid = $('.sectionchoose').val();
    let cat_id;
    if($('#asd').val()){
         cat_id = $('#asd').val();
    } else {
         cat_id = 0;
    }
    $.ajax({

        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        url : '/admin/selectsection',
        data: {id:sectionid, cat_id:cat_id},

        success: function(response){
            $('.categorylist').html(response)
        }, error:function(){

        }
    })
})
```

****Step 4**:** Send the session value to your dependent blade again (as `cat_id` here)

```
 public function findCategories(Request $request){
        if($request->json()){
            $data = $request->all();
            $cat_id = $data['cat_id'] ?? '';
            $categories = Category::where(['section_id' => $data['id'], 'status'=>1])->get()->toArray();
            return view('admin.deal-management.categorylist',compact('categories','cat_id'));

        }
    }
```

**Done!** As far as I know, there is not any other way to get old value of dependent dropdown list value so far.